# ZeroMQ in go won't print my json message bytes received from PULL socket

Tags: json, node.js, go, zeromq

I'm trying a simple code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    zmq "github.com/alecthomas/gozmq"
)

func main() {
    context, _ := zmq.NewContext()
    defer context.Close()

    //  Socket to receive messages on
    receiver, _ := context.NewSocket(zmq.PULL)
    defer receiver.Close()
    receiver.Connect("tcp://localhost:5557")

    //  Process tasks forever
    for {
        msgbytes, _ := receiver.Recv(0)
    fmt.Println("received")
        fmt.Println(string(msgbytes))
    }
}
```

In NodeJS I send messages like this:

```
console.log(payload);
sender.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
```

I can see the json in the console, so `sender.sen()` is actually sending things. Also, the output from the `.go` program for each payload is:

```
received
[]
received
[]
```

There's no output. I've searched the [GoDocs](https://godoc.org/github.com/zeromq/goczmq) for the `Recv` method and there's no separation like `recv_json, recv_message, etc` like in other languages, it's all bytes. So what's happening? I'm sending a string because it's sent as stringfy, right?

**UPDATE**

As Nehal said below, I changed the import statement to the official rep, and this is the new code:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    zmq "gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq.v4"
)

func main() {
    //  Socket to receive messages on
    receiver, _ := zmq.NewPull("tcp://*:5557")
    defer receiver.Destroy()

    //  Process tasks forever
    for {
        request, _ := receiver.RecvMessage()
    fmt.Println("received")
        fmt.Println(request)
    }
}
```

But this time 'received' isn't even printed, it seems that no message is being received at all

Comment: Try `goczmq`. https://godoc.org/github.com/zeromq/goczmq#Sock.RecvMessage

Comment: @NehalJWani I updated the code, would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server in go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    zmq "gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq.v4"
)

func main() {
    //  Socket to receive messages on
    receiver, err := zmq.NewPull("tcp://*:5557")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer receiver.Destroy()

    //  Process tasks forever
    for {
        request, err := receiver.RecvMessage()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Received: '%s'\n", request)
    }
}
```

Client in Node.js:

```
var zmq = require('zmq')
  , sock = zmq.socket('push');

sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5557');
setInterval(function(){
   console.log('Sending data');
   sock.send(JSON.stringify({'msg': 'Hi There!'}));
}, 500);
```

Server Side:

```
$ go run a.go
Received: '[{"msg":"Hi There!"}]'
Received: '[{"msg":"Hi There!"}]'
...
```

Client Side:

```
$ node a.js 
Sending data
Sending data
...
```

RecvMessage Documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/zeromq/goczmq#Sock.RecvMessage

Node.js package: https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node

Excellent zmq examples in go: https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/tree/master/examples/Go

Nice getting started tutorial: http://taotetek.github.io/oldschool.systems/post/goczmq1/

Comment: Why you provided the full address for the nodejs but not for the go? Is there any difference? I'm trying tcp://*:5557 for both and I'm gettind address already in use

Comment: The `pull` code is going to _listen_ on all interfaces for incoming tcp connections on port 5557, hence: `tcp://*:5557`. The `push` code is going to  _connect_ to the port 5557 over tcp on a particular interface, in this case being `127.0.0.1` aka `localhost`.